# How to speed up SSL connection establishment?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ssl, openssl

I have an OpenSSL setup on my Linux PC using Apache2.

NO, I haven't enabled DNS resolving.
I have the certificate on the machine, LOCALLY.

Still, Chrome devtools tell me that `Initial Connection took 1.64 s`. That's a lot of waiting for me when it comes to refreshing the page after a specific time has passed.

How to speed that up or is that the way it's supposed to be?

**PS:** I'm using StartCom's free ssl.

Comment: What is the time without SSL

Comment: 2ms (I'm in the same network as the server).

Comment: This is not very exact for me. What I want is either a config option or a simple script in any language.

Comment: You question is generic it's not like you had a very detailed question

Comment: I suspect issue is a certificate issue doesn't matter what you want

Comment: Never mind, solved it myself instead using the link mentioned earlier.

Comment: The pain point in SSL/TLS is key exchange. Its the part that limits throughput, and its not uncommon to only be able to perform 500 or so key exchanges a second because Diffie-Hellman is computationally expensive (bulk encryption with AES or TripleDES is relatively easy, and that's where 1000's of concurrent connections arise). But any semi-modern machines (including cell phones and tablets) should be able to do better than 1.5 seconds for one exchange. Your problem is likely elsewhere unless you picked an outrageous key size. For example, RSA-2048 requires 100x more computation than RSA-1024.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use StartCom.

Instead, use Let's Encrypt, with the `--apache` autoconfig option.

It will ask you everything user-friendly and you can fully customize your Apache config after setting up the Let's Encrypt SSL.

So, the problem is solved by deleting the StartCom SSL and auto-configuring apache with Let's Encrypt.

I don't really know what's the initial problem here, but Let's Encrypt seems to be optimized better.

Answer (score 5):

There are several areas to improve SSL connection (and general SSL traffic latency). Some of these may impact security in some small or great way.

(These are for ssl.conf using Apache)

**Disable the Domain lookup, and allow Non-SNI to reach primary domain**

- SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

**Instead of named hosts, use IP address for the :443 VHOST entry**

**Cache SSL Sessions**

- SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
- SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

Allow for **faster SSL Protocol order**, general compatibility, medium security:

- SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
- SSLCipherSuite ALL:+HIGH:+TLSv1:!ADH:!EXP:!SSLv2:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!NULL:!aNULL
- SSLHonorCipherOrder on

**OCSP Stapling (speeds up SSL)**

- SSLUseStapling                   on
- SSLStaplingResponderTimeout      5
- SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
- SSLStaplingCache                 shmcb:/run/ocsp(128000)

**HSTS (can do preload so http:// requests become https:// requests in the browser**

- Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"

Submit for preload here: https://hstspreload.appspot.com/

Consider the following more advanced implementations:

- HTTP/2 with HPACK
- Brotli Compression

Other non-SSL issues that may help speed up connnection

Another directive for Apache in httpd.conf

- HostnameLookups Off

Comment: I agree with @ForceMagic below regarding Let's Encrypt as well, though I don't know if it is better than StartCom SSL, I do know it is free and also is not too difficult to implement and manage.

Comment: Nice explanation, well-written and (kind of) easy to understand. Thanks! +1